# Can not insert data CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Why I can't insert data use form?

Which is a problem, if I use this, data can not be saved:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/Ca_pendaftar/tambah" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="demo_form2">
```

But if I use this, the data can be saved:

```
<?= form_open_multipart('admin/ca_pendaftar/tambah', ['class'=>'form-horizontal']) ?>
```

in here im use vendors or plugin data-parsley-validate for validate field

Comment: Any error message??

Comment: No error message

Comment: show your insert query

Comment: Which is a problem, if I use this, data can not be saved :
`<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/Ca_pendaftar/tambah" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="demo_form2">`

But if I use this, the data can be saved :
`<?= form_open_multipart('admin/ca_pendaftar/tambah', ['class'=>'form-horizontal']) ?>`

in here im use vendors or plugin data-parsley-validate for validate field

Comment: @YadhuBabu help me please

Comment: you just remove `data-parsley-validate` and `id="demo_form2"` from your form then check.

Comment: @YadhuBabu Yes, if it is deleted then data can be input, but validation from parsley's plug-in can not work

Comment: Using giant bold fonts does not give your question more importance or priority over others, nor does it make it any easier to understand.  Removed.

Comment: Have you done any basic troubleshooting at all?  Compare the ***rendered*** HTML of the form that works to the rendered HTML of the form that doesn't work.  What's different?

Comment: @EkaWahyuSholeha is it necessary to use `parsley's plug-in` for client side validation. you can use some other validation plugin for client side validation . `jquery validation engine` is simple and easy to install or check check your console and find out the errors

Answer (score 1):

```
<form
  method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/Ca_pendaftar/tambah"
  data-parsley-validate
  class="form-horizontal form-label-left" id="demo_form2">
====================================================================

    $this->input->post();
```

Hello,
Make sure that your html `tag(<input> <select>, etc...)` name was there and its gets in `"admin/Ca_pendaftar/tambah"` controlles.

- You can also write `"$this->input->post();"` fist line of "tambah" functions and check all posted data into there.

Comment: done,  I've written it in the controller
But, still can not

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in client side validation. you are using `data-parsley-validate` for your client side validation. check your console to find out errors or you can use `jquery-validationEngine` for client side validation which is simple and easy to install.

In you head tag add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In your footer

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"</script>

<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#id_of_your_form").validationEngine();
        });

            </script>
```

In your form

```
<form action="submit" id="contact-form" method="post" name="id_of_your_form">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]" />
```

in your input type you can add your validations inside class

```
class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]],custom[email],custom[phone]"
```

> http://me.position-absolute.com/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html